# Adding a table of data to a dictionary excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I'm brand new to using dictionaries and could do with a bit of help. I've got a table of data in range A1:C4

A   B   C
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6   9

Is there any way of adding this tables directly into a dictionary?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate? It is unclear what you are trying to achieve from your question and so it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I'm given to understand that a dictionary can hold 1 key and 1 table of values together i.e. key = "myRange", values = table. Is this correct, if so how do i do it?

Comment: What you've been tasked with (putting a range in a dictionary so you can use it as the datasource for a SQL statement) is not something that's going to work. Either you mis-understood the request or the requestor doesn't know VBA either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim c As Excel.Range

Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set r = Range("a1:c4")

For Each c In r.Cells
    d.Add CStr(c.Address), c.Value
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks nathan but thats not quite what i'm after. I was wondering if the dictionary can take the table as a whole as i have to run SQL across it later. Thanks

Comment: Is something like this valid?

Comment: d.Add "myTable", Range("a1:c4")

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're probably looking for is a `Multidimensional Array`

A standard `Array` will hold a series of values in a list, and the value of any point in this list can be referenced, for example:

```
myArray = Array("One", "Two", "Three")

'The first value in an array is at position 0 unless otherwise specified
MsgBox myArray(0) 'Will open a message box with the value "One"
MsgBox myArray(1) 'Will open a message box with the value "Two"
MsgBox myArray(2) 'Will open a message box with the value "Three"
```

Whereas a standard array is one dimensional, using a `Multidimensional Array` allows you to add more than one dimension to this list. Put simply a two dimensional array will let you create a table of data.

`dim myArray(1 to 3, 1 to 3) as Variant` will create a two dimensional array, by also specifying '1 to 3' will allocate a set size and range of items that can be referenced in the array. Take for example this table:

A    B    C

D    E    F

G    H    I

To put this into a multidimensional array would be the following

```
Dim myArray(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Variant

myArray(1, 1) = "A"
myArray(1, 2) = "B"
myArray(1, 3) = "C"
myArray(2, 1) = "D"
myArray(2, 2) = "E"
myArray(2, 3) = "F"
myArray(3, 1) = "G"
myArray(3, 2) = "H"
myArray(3, 3) = "I"

MsgBox myArray(2, 2) 'Will open a message box with the value "E"
```

Given you are looking to produce this from Range("A1:C4") you could use a loop to go through each cell create this:

```
Dim myArray(1 To 4, 1 To 3) As Variant

For Each c In Range("A1:C4")
    myArray(c.Row, c.Column) = c.Value
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks for that Oliver. Unfortunately i can't use a multi-dimensional array. The brief i've been given is to put that range of data in a dictionary then apparently i can use that dictionary in the FROM clause of a SQL statement. It's a challenge as i've never done either. Happy times!

Comment: Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

d.Add "myTable", Range("a1:c4")